# Linq to Select a Parent based on Attribute of a Nested Child

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am using System.Xml.Linq in order to get the information I need from this XML file.  I need to end up with a List of the referenceId's that have the correct entityType in the child element.

Here is a sample of the XML file I am working with.

```
<PropertySetBindings>
<PropertySetBind referenceId="assemblies">
  <Rules>
    <Include entityType="IfcElementAssembly" subtypes="true" />
  </Rules>
</PropertySetBind>
<PropertySetBind referenceId="beam_common">
  <Rules>
    <Include entityType="IfcBeam" subtypes="false" />
  </Rules>  
</PropertySetBind>
<PropertySetBind referenceId="column_common">
  <Rules>
    <Include entityType="IfcColumn" subtypes="false" />
  </Rules>  
</PropertySetBind>
```

This is the best Linq query I can come up with, but it doesn't return anything.  Nothing seems to work as soon as I try to query the attributes

```
 var bindings = xElement.Elements("PropertySetBindings")
   .Elements("PropertySetBind")
   .Where(x => x.Elements("Rules")
   .Elements("Include")                           
   .Attributes("entityType").FirstOrDefault().Equals("IfcBeam"))
   .Select(x => x.Attribute("referenceId"));
```

I think this might have to do with accessing the value of the attribute.  There is no property for Attributes("entityType").Value  Also, if I try to simply return all the "entityType" attributes, it returns the name and value of the attribute:

[image]

I think this query is complex for a couple reasons.

1. Depth of the XML Tree (nested children).
2. The need to use the attribute values.

Let me know if anyone knows how to do this type of Linq query.

Comment: `.Attributes("entityType").FirstOrDefault().Value == "IfcBeam")`

Answer (score 1):

```
var referenceIds = xElement.Element("PropertySetBindings")
    .Elements("PropertySetBind")
    .Where(x => x.Elements("Rules")
        .Any(r => r.Elements("Include")
            .Any(i => i.Attributes("entityType")
                .Any(a => a.Value == "IfcBeam")
            )
        )
    )
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("referenceId"))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

It works as follows:

1. select the `PropertySetBindings` element
2. select the `PropertySetBind` children
3. filter the children to children with `Rules` elements, that have `Include` elements that have `entityType` attributes, that have a value of 'IfcBeam'.
4. from those `PropertySetBind` elements, select the 'referenceId' attribute
5. check for null (attribute exists)
6. select the value of the attribute (so you dont have the "referenceId=value", just the value)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm learning a lot from your fancy pants query!

Comment: If this helps you, consider an upvote, or marking this answer as accepted. This is an easy way for the community to see that it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a working solution!
I can only get it to work with using this query notation (I think its called) instead of the Lambda notation.  This allows for accessing the value of the attribute.

```
            var bindings = from binding in xElement.Elements("PropertySetBindings")
                       from bind in binding.Elements("PropertySetBind")
                       from ru in bind.Elements("Rules")
                       from inc in ru.Elements("Include")
                       where (string)inc.Attribute("entityType") == "IfcBeam"
                       select bind.Attribute("referenceId").Value;
```

Let me know if you have a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
 var bindings = xElement.Elements("PropertySetBindings")
    .Elements("PropertySetBind")                       
    .Where(x => x.Elements("Rules").FirstOrDefault()
    .Elements("Include").FirstOrDefault()                         
    .Attributes("entityType").FirstOrDefault().Value.Equals("IfcBeam"))
    .Select(x => x.Attributes("referenceId").FirstOrDefault().Value);
```